# GetThreadContext winapi call with python / ctypes

Tags: python, windows, winapi, 64-bit, ctypes

I'm currently working on a Python/Winapi project. 
I want to call Get- and SetThreadContext with Python and ctypes.
My setup is Windows10 64bit and Python 64bit. The Apis should work for both, 32bit and 64bit processes.
It does work with 32bit processes by calling Wow64GetThreadContext with a WOW64Context.
However with 64bit processes and Get/SetThreadContex it does not work.

GetLastError does show 87 (The parameter is incorrect.) 
Probably the implementation of my Context64 is wrong but I couldn't find a mistake.
I tried it also with the Implementation from https://github.com/MarioVilas/winappdbg 
Both implementations show a size of 1232 with ctypes.sizeof(ctx).

My current implementation of CONTEXT for x64:

```
WORD        = ctypes.c_ushort
BYTE        = ctypes.c_ubyte
DWORD64     = ctypes.c_ulonglong

CONTEXT_AMD64           = 0x00100000
CONTEXT_CONTROL         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000001)
CONTEXT_INTEGER         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000002)
CONTEXT_SEGMENTS        = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000004)
CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT  = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000008)
CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000010)
CONTEXT_MMX_REGISTERS   = CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT
CONTEXT_FULL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT)
CONTEXT_ALL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS |
                CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS)
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_ACTIVE    = 0x0000000008000000
CONTEXT_SERVICE_ACTIVE      = 0x0000000010000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST   = 0x0000000040000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REPORTING = 0x0000000080000000


class M128A(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("Low", DWORD64),
            ("High", DWORD64)
            ]

class XMM_SAVE_AREA32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('ControlWord', WORD),
                ('StatusWord', WORD),
                ('TagWord', BYTE),
                ('Reserved1', BYTE),
                ('ErrorOpcode', WORD),
                ('ErrorOffset', DWORD),
                ('ErrorSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved2', WORD),
                ('DataOffset', DWORD),
                ('DataSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved3', WORD),
                ('MxCsr', DWORD),
                ('MxCsr_Mask', DWORD),
                ('FloatRegisters', M128A * 8),
                ('XmmRegisters', M128A * 16),
                ('Reserved4', BYTE * 96)
                ]

class DUMMYSTRUCTNAME(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[
              ("Header", M128A * 2),
              ("Legacy", M128A * 8),
              ("Xmm0", M128A),
              ("Xmm1", M128A),
              ("Xmm2", M128A),
              ("Xmm3", M128A),
              ("Xmm4", M128A),
              ("Xmm5", M128A),
              ("Xmm6", M128A),
              ("Xmm7", M128A),
              ("Xmm8", M128A),
              ("Xmm9", M128A),
              ("Xmm10", M128A),
              ("Xmm11", M128A),
              ("Xmm12", M128A),
              ("Xmm13", M128A),
              ("Xmm14", M128A),
              ("Xmm15", M128A)
              ]


class DUMMYUNIONNAME(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_=[
              ("FltSave", XMM_SAVE_AREA32),
              ("DummyStruct", DUMMYSTRUCTNAME)
              ]

class CONTEXT64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("P1Home", DWORD64),
                ("P2Home", DWORD64),
                ("P3Home", DWORD64),
                ("P4Home", DWORD64),
                ("P5Home", DWORD64),
                ("P6Home", DWORD64),
                ("ContextFlags", DWORD),
                ("MxCsr", DWORD),
                ("SegCs", WORD),
                ("SegDs", WORD),
                ("SegEs", WORD),
                ("SegFs", WORD),
                ("SegGs", WORD),
                ("SegSs", WORD),
                ("EFlags", DWORD),
                ("Dr0", DWORD64),
                ("Dr1", DWORD64),
                ("Dr2", DWORD64),
                ("Dr3", DWORD64),
                ("Dr6", DWORD64),
                ("Dr7", DWORD64),
                ("Rax", DWORD64),
                ("Rcx", DWORD64),
                ("Rdx", DWORD64),
                ("Rbx", DWORD64),
                ("Rsp", DWORD64),
                ("Rbp", DWORD64),
                ("Rsi", DWORD64),
                ("Rdi", DWORD64),
                ("R8", DWORD64),
                ("R9", DWORD64),
                ("R10", DWORD64),
                ("R11", DWORD64),
                ("R12", DWORD64),
                ("R13", DWORD64),
                ("R14", DWORD64),
                ("R15", DWORD64),
                ("Rip", DWORD64),
                ("DebugControl", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("DUMMYUNIONNAME", DUMMYUNIONNAME),
                ("VectorRegister", M128A * 26),
                ("VectorControl", DWORD64)
]
```

My code implementation:

```
KERNEL32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32
ctx = constants.CONTEXT64()
ctx.ContextFlags = constants.CONTEXT_FULL
_GetThreadContext = KERNEL32.GetThreadContext
_GetThreadContext.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
_GetThreadContext.restype = ctypes.c_uint
_SetThreadContext = KERNEL32.SetThreadContext
_SetThreadContext.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
_SetThreadContext.restype = ctypes.c_uint

if KERNEL32.SuspendThread(thandle) == -1:
   print("[!] Failed to suspend thread, exit...")
   print("[!] Last error code: " + str(KERNEL32.GetLastError()))
   sys.exit(0)
if not _GetThreadContext(thandle, ctypes.byref(ctx)):
   print("[!] Failed to get thread context, exit...")
   print("[!] Last error code: " + str(KERNEL32.GetLastError()))
   sys.exit(0)
```

Notes: I use notepad for testing as the target process (also tried with puttyx64)
thandle is tested and does work with other calls and suspend.
thandle does have the following permissions (0x0400 | 0x0010 | 0x0020 | 0x0008 | 0x0002 | 0x0040 | 0x0800).
No Python errors
What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

EDIT: Minimal (not)working example (notepad.exe must be running)

```
import ctypes
import time
import sys

WORD = ctypes.c_ushort
BYTE = ctypes.c_ubyte
DWORD64 = ctypes.c_ulonglong
DWORD = ctypes.c_uint
ULONG = ctypes.c_ulong
LONG = ctypes.c_long
CHAR = ctypes.c_char

CONTEXT_AMD64           = 0x00100000
CONTEXT_CONTROL         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000001)
CONTEXT_INTEGER         = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000002)
CONTEXT_SEGMENTS        = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000004)
CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT  = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000008)
CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS = (CONTEXT_AMD64 | 0x00000010)
CONTEXT_MMX_REGISTERS   = CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT
CONTEXT_FULL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT)
CONTEXT_ALL = (CONTEXT_CONTROL | CONTEXT_INTEGER | CONTEXT_SEGMENTS |
                CONTEXT_FLOATING_POINT | CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS)
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_ACTIVE    = 0x0000000008000000
CONTEXT_SERVICE_ACTIVE      = 0x0000000010000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REQUEST   = 0x0000000040000000
CONTEXT_EXCEPTION_REPORTING = 0x0000000080000000


class PROCESSENTRY32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwSize',              DWORD),
        ('cntUsage',            DWORD),
        ('th32ProcessID',       DWORD),
        ('th32DefaultHeapID',   ctypes.POINTER(ULONG)),
        ('th32ModuleID',        DWORD),
        ('cntThreads',          DWORD),
        ('th32ParentProcessID', DWORD),
        ('pcPriClassBase',      LONG),
        ('dwFlags',             DWORD),
        ('szExeFile',           CHAR * 260)
    ]

class THREADENTRY32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('dwSize',              DWORD),
        ('cntUsage',            DWORD),
        ('th32ThreadID',        DWORD),
        ('th32OwnerProcessID',  DWORD),
        ('tpBasePri',           DWORD),
        ('tpDeltaPri',          DWORD),
        ('dwFlags',             DWORD)
    ]


class M128A(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
            ("Low", DWORD64),
            ("High", DWORD64)
            ]

class XMM_SAVE_AREA32(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ('ControlWord', WORD),
                ('StatusWord', WORD),
                ('TagWord', BYTE),
                ('Reserved1', BYTE),
                ('ErrorOpcode', WORD),
                ('ErrorOffset', DWORD),
                ('ErrorSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved2', WORD),
                ('DataOffset', DWORD),
                ('DataSelector', WORD),
                ('Reserved3', WORD),
                ('MxCsr', DWORD),
                ('MxCsr_Mask', DWORD),
                ('FloatRegisters', M128A * 8),
                ('XmmRegisters', M128A * 16),
                ('Reserved4', BYTE * 96)
                ]

class DUMMYSTRUCTNAME(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_=[
              ("Header", M128A * 2),
              ("Legacy", M128A * 8),
              ("Xmm0", M128A),
              ("Xmm1", M128A),
              ("Xmm2", M128A),
              ("Xmm3", M128A),
              ("Xmm4", M128A),
              ("Xmm5", M128A),
              ("Xmm6", M128A),
              ("Xmm7", M128A),
              ("Xmm8", M128A),
              ("Xmm9", M128A),
              ("Xmm10", M128A),
              ("Xmm11", M128A),
              ("Xmm12", M128A),
              ("Xmm13", M128A),
              ("Xmm14", M128A),
              ("Xmm15", M128A)
              ]


class DUMMYUNIONNAME(ctypes.Union):
    _fields_=[
              ("FltSave", XMM_SAVE_AREA32),
              ("DummyStruct", DUMMYSTRUCTNAME)
              ]

class CONTEXT64(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("P1Home", DWORD64),
                ("P2Home", DWORD64),
                ("P3Home", DWORD64),
                ("P4Home", DWORD64),
                ("P5Home", DWORD64),
                ("P6Home", DWORD64),
                ("ContextFlags", DWORD),
                ("MxCsr", DWORD),
                ("SegCs", WORD),
                ("SegDs", WORD),
                ("SegEs", WORD),
                ("SegFs", WORD),
                ("SegGs", WORD),
                ("SegSs", WORD),
                ("EFlags", DWORD),
                ("Dr0", DWORD64),
                ("Dr1", DWORD64),
                ("Dr2", DWORD64),
                ("Dr3", DWORD64),
                ("Dr6", DWORD64),
                ("Dr7", DWORD64),
                ("Rax", DWORD64),
                ("Rcx", DWORD64),
                ("Rdx", DWORD64),
                ("Rbx", DWORD64),
                ("Rsp", DWORD64),
                ("Rbp", DWORD64),
                ("Rsi", DWORD64),
                ("Rdi", DWORD64),
                ("R8", DWORD64),
                ("R9", DWORD64),
                ("R10", DWORD64),
                ("R11", DWORD64),
                ("R12", DWORD64),
                ("R13", DWORD64),
                ("R14", DWORD64),
                ("R15", DWORD64),
                ("Rip", DWORD64),
                ("DebugControl", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastBranchFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionToRip", DWORD64),
                ("LastExceptionFromRip", DWORD64),
                ("DUMMYUNIONNAME", DUMMYUNIONNAME),
                ("VectorRegister", M128A * 26),
                ("VectorControl", DWORD64)
]

KERNEL32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)
PSAPI = ctypes.WinDLL('psapi', use_last_error=True)
name = "notepad.exe"

hSnapshot = KERNEL32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(0x00000002 | 0x00000004, 0)
pe32 = PROCESSENTRY32()
pe32.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32)
processes = []
if KERNEL32.Process32First(hSnapshot, ctypes.byref(pe32)):
    while True:
        processes.append({'pid': pe32.th32ProcessID, 'name': pe32.szExeFile})
        if not KERNEL32.Process32Next(hSnapshot, ctypes.byref(pe32)):
            break

for n in processes:
    if n['name'] == bytes(name, "utf-8"):
        pid = n['pid']
if not pid:
    sys.exit(0)

te32 = THREADENTRY32()
te32.dwSize = ctypes.sizeof(THREADENTRY32)
threads = []
if KERNEL32.Thread32First(hSnapshot, ctypes.byref(te32)):
    while True:
        if te32.th32OwnerProcessID == pid:
            threads.append(te32.th32ThreadID)
        if not KERNEL32.Thread32Next(hSnapshot, ctypes.byref(te32)):
            break

access = (0x0400 | 0x0010 | 0x0020 | 0x0008 | 0x0002 | 0x0040 | 0x0800)
thandle = KERNEL32.OpenThread(access, 0, threads[0])
ctx = CONTEXT64()
ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL
_GetThreadContext = KERNEL32.GetThreadContext
_GetThreadContext.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
_GetThreadContext.restype = ctypes.c_uint
_SetThreadContext = KERNEL32.SetThreadContext
_SetThreadContext.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
_SetThreadContext.restype = ctypes.c_uint
if KERNEL32.SuspendThread(thandle) == -1:
    print("[!] Failed to suspend thread, exit...")
    print("[!] Last error code: " + str(ctypes.get_last_error()))
    sys.exit(0)
if not _GetThreadContext(thandle, ctypes.byref(ctx)):
    print("[!] Failed to get thread context, exit...")
    print("[!] Last error code: " + str(ctypes.get_last_error()))
    sys.exit(0)
if not _SetThreadContext(thandle, ctypes.byref(ctx)):
    print("[!] Failed to set thread context, exit...")
    print("[!] Last error code: " + str(ctypes.get_last_error()))
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Your definition has the floating point and vector registers at the wrong offset, and it could it use improvement in the use of [`_pack_` and `_anonymous_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure._pack_), but it's the right size. I don't see a reason for `GetThreadContext` to fail with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. Please switch to using `kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)`, and check the last error with `ctypes.get_last_error()`. This captures the last error at a low level in C, immediately after the FFI call, so it's guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error 87, with the above code. I just add function [`OpenThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openthread) to get the thread handle:`thandle = KERNEL32.OpenThread(0x0400|0x0010|0x0020|0x0008|0x0002|0x0040|0x0800,0, threadid)`, could you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example?

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I provided a example above. I can't get it to run. I still get an error 87

Comment: The sample works for me, and I've test on python(x64) 3.6.6, 3.7.5 and 3.8.5. BTW, could you double check the bit-version of the python like(`n_bits = 32 << bool(sys.maxsize >> 32)
print(n_bits)`)? Because I can get the 87 error if I use 32-bit python.

Comment: Oh boy. It is working now. Thank you very much. I'm a bit confused because I was able to get handles to x64 processes with x32 Python. I thought this is not possible.

Comment: However, your structure definition is still wrong compared to the definition for x64 in winnt.h.

Comment: Actual kernel handles aren't restricted to 32-bit or 64-bit processes, and their values are limited to less than 32-bit. But under WOW64 emulation, a thread context is completely different from the native x64 thread context. It's emulating an x86 32-bit CPU.